# Mysql locked on INTERNAL DDL LOG RECOVER IN PROGRESS

Tags: mysql

Mysql process is using up 100% cpu. show processlist shows that mysql seems to have a system lock because of "INTERNAL DDL LOG RECOVER IN PROGRESS".

Searching for this doesn't return meaningful results so: what is this lock all about? How to fix this?

Mysql version 5.6.14-log

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? Im facing the same issue but without the CPU usage...

Comment: No solution yet... I tried running auto repair and other recovery options with no success. CPU usage sometimes is lower than 100% but the lock is always there... Didn't try to update mysql version yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have some in the tables MySQL uses to store database definitions.

Your best option is to let MySQL try an recover.

Check disk space and ensure you have enough free space for MySQL to work normally - this is a common cause of this problem. An unexpected shutdown may also have been the cause.

Once it completes you may want to do a check and repair to make sure all is operational - be away that this may take some time as well.

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases
```

Sometimes the repair may get stuck in a an internal lock, and never seems to stop, if your database is under 1GB and it's taken longer then 30 minutes, kill the mysql server process and try and restart it.

If that still doesn't help, start the server in safe mode and try and take a backup, safe mode can be started with;

```
sudo mysqld_safe
```

Comment: No luck using mysqlcheck. INTERNAL DDL LOG RECOVER IN PROGRESS appears right after starting up mysql and is there forever...

Comment: How did starting in safe mode go?

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,615079,615135#msg-615135 From google, did the server crash?

Answer (score 0):

See related:
[Server stuck in INTERNAL DDL LOG RECOVERY IN PROGRESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476094/server-stuck-in-internal-ddl-log-recovery-in-progress)

This is a known bug in MySQL:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74517

The server does not clear this message when done, causing confusion.

The bug was fixed, you need to upgrade the server:

> Noted in 5.6.25, 5.7.8, 5.8.0 changelogs.
>
> In the Performance Schema threads table, the PROCESSLIST_STATE and
>   PROCESSLIST_INFO values did not change for the thread/sql/main main
>   thread instrument as the thread state changed.