# Server stuck in INTERNAL DDL LOG RECOVERY IN PROGRESS

Tags: mysql

1 month ago, my server had a crash. I had alot of trouble but managed to restore everything.

But,

Now, the first background thread upon startup is locked on "INTERNAL DDL LOG RECOVERY IN PROGRESS" and never stops. **It does not affect the system** as it does not consume any CPU / memory, it simply just starts and never stops.

Ive found many with the same problem but there is no solution for this problem.

I have run a `mysqlcheck` on all tables, and they are all OK.

All tables are of **Innodb**

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

**Mysql version 5.6.13-log**

Comment: Judging by "I have run a mysqlcheck on all tables", you use MyISAM?

Comment: You have an open bounty on this, but I would think it would be better asked over at http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Unhappily most users think Stackoverflow is a "Jack of all trades, master of none".

Comment: Does the log say anything unusual?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski , ok. I will do that.

Comment: Are you using file-per-table mode for your innodb files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in MySQL:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74517

The server does not clear this message when done, causing confusion.

EDIT -- the bug is now fixed:

> Noted in 5.6.25, 5.7.8, 5.8.0 changelogs.
>
> In the Performance Schema threads table, the PROCESSLIST_STATE and
>   PROCESSLIST_INFO values did not change for the thread/sql/main main
>   thread instrument as the thread state changed.

Comment: Marc, I cannot believe Ive missed this. In either way, thank for pointing out the obivous to me. I will simply have to wait for future releases with bugfixes. Thanks again mate!